# Find the interior points of the set $\,A=\left\{\sqrt2+n\,:\,n\in\Bbb N\right\}$ on the usual topology on $\,\Bbb R\,.$

Tags: general-topology

Find the interior points of the set $\,A=\left\{\sqrt2+n\,:\,n\in\Bbb N\right\}$ on the usual topology on $\,\Bbb R\,.$

I think it is the empty set because if $\,p\in A\,$ and $\,p\in U\,,\,$ where $\,U\,$ is an open set, then $\,U\,$ is not a subset of $\,A\,.$

Comment: Arghya, you are right, there does not exist any interior point of the set $A.$

Comment: @Angelo thanks for confirmation

Comment: $A$ is s discrete closed set of $\mathbb{R}$, the [same way](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1270826/121671) that $\mathbb{N}$ is also a discrete and closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question but with usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, $A$ I think gains the discrete topology with the subspace topology and the interior isn't empty but $A$, @Angelo am I wrong?

Comment: @TurquoiseTilt, the interior of the subset $A$ of the topological space $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology is empty, indeed for any $a\in A$ and for any open subset $U(a)$ of $\Bbb R$ which contains $a$, it results that $U(a)\not\subseteq A$.